# Why am i getting this error from getSource method in MouseAdapter?

Tags: java

I was trying to change the text "Java" to "Love Java" by using MouseAdapter. The text "Java" comes out when mouseEntered and "Love Java" comes out when mouseExited. So I created class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter and trying to use the methods.

But there is the error message "The method getSource() is undefined for the type MouseEvent". When I searched it, this code is nothing wrong with it but I don't know why I'm getting this error message, and also of course the result is not working.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseEvent extends JFrame{

    MouseEvent(){
        setTitle("Practicing mouse event");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lb = new JLabel("Java");
        MyMouse mym = new MyMouse();
        lb.addMouseListener(mym);

        lb.setSize(300,100);
        add(lb);
        setSize(400,200);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MouseEvent();
    }
}

class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel lb = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        lb.setText("Love Java");
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel lb = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        lb.setText("Java");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you 'added' MouseListener to the JLabel? If not it's the reason why you ran into troubles

Comment: I added MouseListener like this.
```
JLabel lb = new JLabel("Java");

  MyMouse mym = new MyMouse();

  lb.addMouseListener(mym);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you do import `java.awt.event.MouseEvent`  and not `org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent`?

Comment: hmm,,,I `import java.awt.event.*;` isn't it containing `java.awt.event.MouseEvent`?

Comment: Not when you also `import org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent;` - a single-type-import declaration has precedence over a type-import-on-demand declaration (see JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2). The other possibility is that you have a class `MouseEvent` within the current package or as nested class

Comment: can you show us the "MyMouse" codes?

Comment: @juls Please [edit] your question to include the full `.java` file content of the `MyMouse` class.

Comment: OMG Thanks @ThomasKläger, I literally use the class name as MouseEvent...I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Progman 
 I figured it out but still yes, I'll edit my questions to the full java file. Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: @Joe I edited my question. But the problem was the name of the class... thx for your help tho! :)

Comment: You were "overloading" the mouse listener methods. You made a method `public void mouseEntered( YourClass evt)` another way to help avoid these types of issues is to use `@Override` on the method name, that way the compiler will tell you that you are not overriding a particular method . ( because the argument type was wrong in this case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MouseEvent` object `e` you are using inside `public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)` or `public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)` should be from `java.awt.event.MouseEvent`.

But, as you have named your main class also as `MouseEvent`, in that case the `MouseEvent` object `e` inside `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` methods are actually the object of your main class. That's why it was searching for `getSource()` method in your main class and failed.

Please change your main class name to something other than `MouseEvent`. For example:

```
public class MyMouseEvent extends JFrame {

    MyMouseEvent() {
...
...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyMouseEvent();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved through these changes to the code:

1. Rename the main class of the program so that its name does not conflict with that of the class (java.awt.event.MouseEvent) imported from Java library.
2. Add @Override annotations to mouseEntered and mouseExited methods to avoid compiler warnings
3. Call setVisible(true) on the frame to display after instantiation

**Here is the working example with the above mentioned changes:**

```
// File name: Demo.java 
// This name was chosen to avoid conflict with java.awt.event.MouseEvent

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter{

    // Add @Override annotation to overridden methods
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel lb = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        lb.setText("Love Java");
    }

    // Add @Override annotation to overridden methods
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel lb = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        lb.setText("Java");
    }
}


public class Demo extends JFrame{
    Demo() {
        setTitle("Practicing mouse event");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lb = new JLabel("Java");
        MyMouse mym = new MyMouse();
        lb.addMouseListener(mym);

        lb.setSize(300,100);
        add(lb);
        setSize(400,200); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        // Display the frame
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac Demo.java

> java Demo
```

[image]

Comment: It's a better answer if you can explain the changes you made and why as opposed to just providing code that works.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I updated the answer with description of changes and comments in code.